# Pass form results to another view chtml yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to pass values selected from the dropDownList and numberField to the view 'Report'. There are no errors but the id that is passed is always "2011-00". Can I fix this so that the passed values match the selected ones?

```
echo CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('message/index')), 'post', array('id'=>'filter-form'))
. CHtml::dropDownList('Bulan', $select, 
          array('01' => 'Januari', '02' => 'Februari','03' => 'Maret', '04' => 'April','05' => 'Mei', '06' => 'Juni','07' => 'Juli', '08' => 'Agustus','09' => 'September', '10' => 'Oktober','11' => 'November', '12' => 'Desember'))
. CHtml::numberField('year', $value='2011',$htmlOptions= array ('min'=>'2008', 'max'=>'2099' ))
. CHtml::submitButton('View Monthly Report', array('submit' => $this->createUrl('Report',array('id'=>$value.'-'.$select))))
. CHtml::endForm();
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if it's a silly question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the form in the controller that's invoked upon submitting your form. You will find your values in $_POST['Bulan'] and $_POST['year'].

With what you're doing now, you're getting the same url, regardless of form content.

Edit:

$select and $value arguments in dropDownList and numberField are merely initial form values, not values supplied by the user.